# Error when using IncludeFilter with Async; IncludeFilter does not support Async

Tags: .net-core

I am using Include Filter to filter the include results but i am getting an error regarding IncludeFilter does not support Async

```
 public async Task<Voter> GetVoterById (int VoterId, int OrganzationId) 
 {
 var Voter = await _context.Voters.Where (v => v.Id == VoterId).IncludeFilter 
 (v => v.VotingYears.Where (y => y.OrganizationId == 
 OrganzationId)).FirstOrDefaultAsync ();
 return Voter;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution was to remove IncludeFilter

```
var Voter = await _context.Voters.Where (v => v.Id == VoterId).Include(v => v.VotingYears).FirstOrDefaultAsync ();
Voter.VotingYears = Voter.VotingYears.Where (y => y.OrganizationId == OrganzationId);
return Voter;
```